# javascript / jquery: How do I check if an function has an attached interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function on a page that have `setInterval()` applied such that they execute every given amount of time. How do I check if an function has an interval applied?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I wasn't very clear on what I meant. Revised the question ("function" not "element").

e.g.

```
$ ->
    someFunction = ->
        # do stuff
    setInterval(someFunction)
```

How do I check if `someFunction()` has an interval set?

Comment: What do you mean intervals attached to elements? Can you show how are *attaching* them?

Comment: What do you mean with "element"? A DOM element? You can attach `setInterval` only to the `window` object.

Comment: Sorry, my mind was in two places when I wrote the question. It's edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a wrapper:

```
var fooFunc = function() {
  return 'Hello World';
}
var addInterval = function(func, callback, time) {
  window.setInterval(callback, time);
  func.prototype.hasInterval = true;
}
addInterval(fooFunc, function() {
  ...
}, 1000);
```

To check if a function has a setInterval attached, use:

```
if (fooFunc.prototype.hasInterval) { .. }
```